# Flutter go_router, StatefulShellRoute with Drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I have an app where the home screen has two tabs; for handle the `TabBar` navigation i use a `StatefulShellRoute` where i pass the tabs to `HomeScreen` screen with the `navigatorContainerBuilder` param. In the HomeScreen i have a `Drawer` that has other app routes like settings or account. to navigate to `AccountScreen` i make a push and i can back to the HomeScreen with AppBar BackButton, but if i am in the web, and try to enter directly to `AccountScreen` by url, I can't back to home because there is not more routes in the Stack. My workaround was to set manually a leading in AppBar and navigate to the HomeScreen with `context.go()`, but this means that i have to do the same thing in every screen that is accessible trough the drawer, and also i can't make a pop with the browser back button. this is an example of the code:

```dart
GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  initialLocation: '/splash',
  routes: [
    ///------------ HOME SCREEN (2 TABS) ------------///
    StatefulShellRoute(
      builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
        return navigationShell;
      },
      navigatorContainerBuilder: (context, navigationShell, children) {
        return HomeShell(navigationShell: navigationShell, children: children);
      },
      branches: [
        ///------------ TAB 1 ------------///
        StatefulShellBranch(
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/tab1',
              builder: (context, state) => const Tab1(),
            )
          ]
        ),
        
        ///------------ TAB 2 ------------///
        StatefulShellBranch(
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/tab2',
              builder: (context, state) => const Tab2(),
            )
          ]
        )
      ], 
    ),
    
    ///------------ ACCOUNT SCREEN ------------///
    GoRoute(
      path: '/account',
      name: AccountScreen.name,
      builder: (context, state) => const AccountScreen(),
    ),
  ]
);
```

I can't create a parent GoRoute because StatefulShellRoute and GoRoute are different type, so i don't know if there will be some way to do what i want. I would appreciate any advice or opinion.